MSAL in next js app deployed in azure causing logout issue
I've used these libs for MSAL implementation in next js app deployed in Azure:
"@azure/msal-browser": "3.2.0",
"@azure/msal-node": "2.15.0",
"@azure/msal-react": "2.1.1",

Here is the description of my problem.
Use case 1: when the app loads and user signs in to the application and tries to sign out, this sign out works as expected.
Use case 2: the issue occurs when the app loads and user signs in, navigates to other pages, and then later tries to sign out; the sign out fails with this error:

ClientConfigurationError: url_parse_error: URL could not be parsed into appropriate segments.
BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API

Both use cases work fine locally, the issue only occurs in a deployed environment.
Please update if any other info required.
This is the sign out handler:
const handleSignOut = async () => {
    if (inProgress !== InteractionStatus.None) {
      console.log(inProgress + " already in progress.");
      return;
    }
    console.log("envVars", envVars);
    if (!envVars.cloudInstance || !envVars.tenantId) {
      console.error(
        "envVars Invalid authority URL cloudInstance",
        envVars.cloudInstance
      );
      console.error("envVars Invalid authority URL tenantId", envVars.tenantId);
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    deleteCookie("access_token");
    setIsLogoutInProgress(true);
    sessionStorage.removeItem(MSAL_INTERACTION_STATUS);
    try {
      if (inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
        await instance.logoutRedirect({
          postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
          account: instance.getActiveAccount(),
        });
      } else {
        console.error("MSAL interaction in progress or status is invalid.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      setIsLogoutInProgress(false);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };


please share your code what you've tried.

@SirraSneha shared in post, thanks!

Are you using azure web app or azure static web app?

@SirraSneha using azure web app

I created a sample Next.js application and successfully signed out, navigating to another page.
I got the same issue when I tried your code, I've changed the code as below
My page.js file:
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { InteractionStatus } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; 

const Dashboard = () => {
    const { instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
    const router = useRouter();  
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isLogoutInProgress, setIsLogoutInProgress] = useState(false);
    const envVars = {
        cloudInstance: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUD_INSTANCE,
        tenantId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TENANT_ID,
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Loaded Environment Variables:", envVars);
    }, []);
    const handleSignOut = async () => {
        if (inProgress !== InteractionStatus.None) {
            console.log("Logout already in progress.");
            return;
        }
        if (!envVars.cloudInstance || !envVars.tenantId) {
            console.error("Invalid environment variables", envVars);
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        setIsLogoutInProgress(true);
        try {
            sessionStorage.removeItem("msalInteractionStatus");          
            await instance.logoutRedirect({
                postLogoutRedirectUri: "/", 
                account: instance.getActiveAccount(),
            });
            router.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Logout error:", error);
        } finally {
            setIsLogoutInProgress(false);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <button onClick={handleSignOut} disabled={isLogoutInProgress}>
                {isLogoutInProgress ? "Logging out..." : "Logout"}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Dashboard;


I've added the useRouter to handle navigation correctly.
Also added router.push("/") in my code to navigate to the home page after logout.
Make sure you add the below environment variables in you configuration section of the Azure Web App.


Here's the Output after deployment.


Successfully signed out.


Can you also verify use case 2 mentioned create one more page, and try to logout after navigation on client side? I tried useRouter as suggested facing same issue still.
Use case 2: the issue occurs when the app loads and user signs in, navigates to other pages, and then later tries to sign out; the sign out fails with this error:

thank you for checking this, please let me know if you face the same issue or not.

@Hrdk Dashboard is my other page and it worked fine for me, once try deleting the cookies and then login again, also make sure you add environment variables to your azure app service.
